# plotly installation with R

Tags: r, plotly

i want to install plotly package in R, from github

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ropensci/plotly")
```

and i have an error message:

```
Downloading github repo ropensci/plotly@master
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

i have searched on the internet and i found that it's a problem of proxy, i tried:

```
set_config(
use_proxy(url="https://github.com/ropensci/plotly", port=8080, username="***",password="***")
)
```

but still have the same problem, i don't know what to put in url and port values, i have two accounts on Githup and plotly

thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only a proxy problem if your network (probably employer) uses a proxy server on their perimeter.

If it *really* is a proxy, problem you'll have to use a different method to set the proxy for plotly operations, since it uses `curlPerform` from `RCurl` directly. Something like this:

```
opts <- list(
  proxy         = "YOUR_PROXY_HTTP_URL",
  proxyusername = "YOUR_PROXY_USERNAME", 
  proxypassword = "YOUR_PROXY_PASSWORD", 
  proxyport     = YOUR_PROXY_PORT
)

options(RCurlOptions = opts)
```

*before* you do any plotly operations.

You will need to use the values provided by your employer or network provider (i.e. *not* GitHub or plotly) for those values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are in some special network that your network administrator restricts the access to the address (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly) though a different port (8080).

To set a proxy, please replace the target URL (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly) with the a proxy web address. Namely, change your code to:

`set_config(use_proxy(url="proxy.aaa.com", port=8080)`

Assuming this `proxy.aaa.com` is the proxy you can use, but this should not be your target address.

More information, can try `?use_proxy`